# Cannot create file on SD card on certain Android devices

Tags: android

I have some rather strange behavior with my app

Some users are reporting the app crashing and after logging / event monitoring I have discovered that the app can not create a directory on the sd card on some phones

I check if the SD card is present then then check if my file is there .minidata

If .minidata is not present I try to create it, however it seems the file cannot be created and file.mkdir returns false

I have the following permission

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

So why does  file.mkdir fail sometimes?

Comment: What path are you using when you try to create .minidata?

Comment: I first check if SD card is mounted then Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/.minidata/"

Answer (score 1):

External storage is not always available on a device. For instance, it may have been mounted on the user's computer. You can check and monitor the state of the external storage using the sample code shown in the docs for [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

Comment: I always check if the storage is mounted and then try to write the dir

So I know 100% the SD card is mounted but the file creation fails

Do you think it could be related to the dir containing . ?

Comment: @user1177292 I don't think it's the file name; it's more likely a problem to be writing to the top-level directory of external storage. See ["Accessing files on external storage"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles) for a better place to put the file. Also, it's better to construct the File using `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path_to_file)` rather than concatenating strings.

Comment: As an example, this happens for about 4-5 users per thousand, so I cannot see this being a issue with creating a file to the top level as lots of other apps do this.

Comment: @user1177292 Do you have any insight into what kind of devices are having the problem?

Comment: I just got a email from one of the guys saying he has a Samsung Galaxy. So as this device has internal and SD external and assuming Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns sdcard and I don't have the WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE could that explain this issue?

Comment: @user1177292 - I don't think that's the problem; the external storage directory should only require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. But I don't have direct experience with that device. Is it possible that the user is plugging in a usb cable between the time you check that the device is mounted and when you try to write the file?

Comment: I asked that and he said no, but as samsung has two sd card it treating one as internal. I am going to issues a update today with logging to track when the file cannot be created along with the model name and added the WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: So its sees the majority of the users who are having issues are Samsung users (the models are mainly GT*), so whats the best way to proceed with this and i assume this is a known issue as many developers would have come across this?